# Using str.replace to replace letters in a string at different placeholders of the string

Tags: python, string

I have a problem that I am working on. The goal of the problem is to take the string placeholder `i`. If `i` is an even placeholder, replace the letter at `i` with the letter at `i -1`. If the `i` place holder is odd, then replace the letter `i` with the letter at `i +1`.

Here is my code so far:

```
def easyCrypto (s):
    for i in range (0,len(s)-1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            str(s).replace(i,((i-1)))
        if i % 2 != 0:
            str(s).replace(i,((i+2)))
    print (s)
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    easyCrypto('abc')
  File "C:/Python/cjakobhomework7.py", line 4, in easyCrypto
    str(s).replace(i,((i-1)))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

update!!

New code based on answers:

```
def easyCrypto (s):
    for i in range (0,len(s)-1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            s =  str(s).replace(s(i),(s(i-1)))
        else:
            s = s.replace(s(i), s(i + 1))
    print (s)
```

However I still have the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    easyCrypto('abc')
  File "C:/Python/cjakobhomework7.py", line 4, in easyCrypto
    s =  str(s).replace(s(i),(s(i-1)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any ideas? thank you

Comment: The problem is that `i` is an _integer_ whereas `str.replace` expects its arguments to be _strings_.

Answer (score 2):

Use `s[i]` instead of `s(i)`, and likewise for the other indexes.

Comment: can you please tell me if I am correct in the proper usage of () and [] brackets. () for indexes but i use [] in this case because I am asking for the letters in the positions of the index. Correct?

Comment: Use `s(i)` if `s` is a function which takes one argument, and you want to call it with the argument `i`. Use `s[i]` if `s` is a string and you need the `i`th character of it. The syntax `s[i]` is (informally) called indexing, and the index is `i`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here:

1. `str.replace` does not automatically stringify its arguments.  You need to manually convert them into strings.  Remember that: "Explicit is better than implicit."
2. `str.replace` does not work in-place because strings are immutable in Python.  You need to reassign `s` to the new string object returned by `str.replace`.

Your code should be:

```
s = s.replace(str(i), str(i-1))
```

Also, you can replace `if i % 2 != 0:` with `else:` since the condition of the second if-statement can only be true if the first is false:

```
if i % 2 == 0:
   s = s.replace(str(i), str(i-1))
else:
   s = s.replace(str(i), str(i+1))
```

---

Regarding your edited question, you are trying to call the string `s` as a function by placing parenthesis after it.  You need to use square brackets to index the string:

```
>>> 'abcde'[0]
'a'
>>> 'abcde'[3]
'd'
>>>
```

In your case it would be:

```
s =  s.replace(s[i], s[i-1])
```

As a general rule of thumb, parenthesis `(...)` are for calling functions while square brackets `[...]` are for indexing sequences/containers.

Comment: @pts I am unsure to what you are refering

Comment: @ChristopherJakob - I have updated my answer to reflect your new question.  In future though, you should not edit new problems into your question.  Doing so invalidates answers as well as confuses people.  Instead, it is best to ask a new question regarding the new problem.

Comment: @pts oh ok thank you for letting me know the proper way to do such things =)